# outlook html email tables mis-aligned

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I've got an Outlook 07/10 table alignment issue that I just can't seem to solve...

Here's what it looks like: http://postimg.org/image/lrizj0h0t/ and obviously the buttons are supposed to line up (ignore the weird text alignment - it's because it's been photoshopped very very quickly for anonymity!!)

I've tried adding extra tables around it, tried making the buttons narrower, tried adding `valign` to various parts of it (including the table it's in). I thought it might be the 'fun' "Outlook is really Word" rendering issue where it's adding a page break, but doesn't appear to be (in that none of the solutions I'd found to fix that, like adding extra tables to make it separate tables and thus not as long, have worked)

Here's the code (i've not included the `html` `body` etc tags, but rest assured, they're there.

```css
<style type="text/css">
body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;}
.ReadMsgBody{width:100%;}
.ExternalClass{width:100%;}
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
#outlook a{padding:0;}
.showonmobile {
 display: none!important;
 }
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 table[class="main"] {
 width: 300px!important;
 } 
 table[class="centermob"] {
 text-align: center!important;
 width: 300px!important;
 }
 td[class="hideonmobile"] {
 display: none!important;
 }
 table[class="hideonmobile"] {
 display: none!important;
 }
 tr[class="hideonmobile"] {
 display: none!important;
 }
    img[class="hideonmobile"] {
 display: none!important;
 }
 table[class="showonmobile"] {
 display: initial!important;
 }
 td[class="showonmobile"] {
 display: initial!important;
 }
 img[class="halfwidth"] {
 width: 300px!important;
 }
 table[class="halfwidth"] {
 width: 300px!important;
 }
    td[class="halfwidth"] {
 width: 300px!important;
 }
 table[class="hidespace"] {
 display: none!important;
 }
 table[class="thirdwidth"] {
 width: 48%!important;
 }
 img[class="onethirdleft"] {
 width: 48%!important;
 }
 img[class="onethirdright"] {
 width: 48%!important;
 }
 table[class="thirdwidthcontact"] {
 display: none!important;
 }
 table[class="thirdwidthwhy"] {
 width: 300px!important;
 }
 td[class="centralise"] {
 text-align: center;
 }
 span[class="showlinebreak"] {
 display: initial!important;
 }
 table[class="hidingonweb"] {
 display: initial!important;
 }
 td[class="nav"] {
 width: 206px!important;
 }
 table[class="twocol"] {
 width: 300px!important;
 }
 img[class="oneninethrees"] {
 width: 140px!important;
 }
        table[class="bottombuttonright"] {
          width: 140px!important;
          float: right!important;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        table[class="bottombuttonleft"] {
          width: 140px!important;
          float: left!important;
          display: inline-block;
        }
 td[class="bottombuttoninner"] {
 width: 82px!important;
        font-size: 13px!important; 
 }
 table[class="bottombuttoninner"] {
 width: 82px!important;
        font-size: 13px!important; 
 }
        td[class="smallerfont"] {
        font-size: 13px!important; 
        }
}
 </style>
```

```html
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="twocol" style="width: 620px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse; empty-cells: show;">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td valign="top" align="center">
  <table align="left" class="bottombuttonleft" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="empty-cells: show; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
   </td>
   <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
   <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <table align="left" width="17" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
  <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
  <table align="left" class="bottombuttonright" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
   </td>
   <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
   <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="hideonmobile" align="left" width="17" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
  <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
  <table align="left" class="bottombuttonleft" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
   </td>
   <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
   <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <table align="left" class="showonmobile" width="20" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
  <!--[if mso]></td></tr><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <table align="left" class="bottombuttonleft" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
   </td>
   <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
   <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="hideonmobile" align="left" width="17" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
  <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
  <table align="left" class="bottombuttonright" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
   </td>
   <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
   <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="hideonmobile" align="left" width="17" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
  <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
  <table height="55" align="left" valign="top" class="bottombuttonleft" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:193px; color: #ffffff; width:193px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="193">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
   </td>
   <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="135">
   <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="135">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
    <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
   <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
   <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Any ideas gratefully received!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put tds around all elements for outlook. There are several points at which you just have 2 table elements in one td. Another problem with Outlook is you can't completely hide a table, so even the showonmobile table you have needs to be in its own td.
I noticed you used `<!--[if mso]>` to add your tds for outlook. You should just have tds on all platforms as it's good practice for emails.

Here's the amended code (using `<!--[if mso]>` for the tds):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="twocol" style="width: 620px; background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse; empty-cells: show;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
        <table align="left" class="bottombuttonleft" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="empty-cells: show; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
            </td>
            <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
            <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
        <table align="left" width="17" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
        <table align="left" class="bottombuttonright" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
            </td>
            <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
            <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
        <table class="hideonmobile" align="left" width="17" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
        <table align="left" class="bottombuttonleft" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
            </td>
            <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
            <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
        <table align="left" class="showonmobile" width="20" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
        <!--[if mso]></td></tr><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <table align="left" class="bottombuttonleft" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
            </td>
            <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
            <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
        <table class="hideonmobile" align="left" width="17" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
        <table align="left" class="bottombuttonright" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:195px; color: #ffffff; width:195px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="195">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
            </td>
            <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="137">
            <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="137">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
        <table class="hideonmobile" align="left" width="17" style="font-size: 15px;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
        <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
        <table height="55" align="left" valign="top" class="bottombuttonleft" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; max-width:193px; color: #ffffff; width:193px; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; background-color: #ffffff;" width="193">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="22">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="border: 0; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctaleftwhite.jpg" style="width: 22px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="22" /> </a></p>
            </td>
            <td class="bottombuttoninner" align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="135">
            <table class="bottombuttoninner" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="40" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; height: 40px; background-color: #ec6608; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;" valign="middle" width="135">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="smallerfont" height="40" style="height: 40px; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; background-color: #ec6608; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 16px;">
                <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;border: 0px;" target="_blank">Text here</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" height="40" width="36">
            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;margin:0;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img height="40" src="ctarightwhite.jpg" style="width: 36px; margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; text-decoration: none; height: 40px;" width="36" /> </a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" style="font-size: 15px; background-color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: thank you!!! The multiple tables in one cell is for the responsive design (to flip to a 3 row/2 column layout rather than 2row/3 column. However, of COURSE adding the extra `[if mso]`'s did it - the spacing tables were a very late addition and I totally wasn't thinking!! You're an amazing human being and you've quite literally made my week! Thank you!

Comment: Haha. No problem, glad it worked for you. Fyi, if you want to quickly check how something will look in Outlook 2010, just open your HTML in Word 2010. It's the same about 99% of the time.